# Does copy constructor call default constructor to create an object

Tags: c++

Does copy constructor call default constructor while creating an object in C++? If I hide the default constructor, I should be still able to created the copy, right?

Comment: It is not clear what "default constructor" you have in mind. There are default constructors that C++ would provide when your code does not have  them and you do not specify an explicit `delete`. Then there are parameterless constructors that are also called "default", but your class is not required to have one of these.

Comment: No matter for my question. Both are default and I don't care is it compiler generated or programmer defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deleting the default constructor does not prevent you from copying the object. Of course you need a way to produce the object in the first place, i.e. you need to provide a non-default constructor.

```
struct Demo {
    Demo() = delete;
    Demo(int _x) : x(_x) { cout << "one-arg constructor" << endl; }
    int x;
};

int main() {
    Demo a(5); // Create the original using one-arg constructor
    Demo b(a); // Make a copy using the default copy constructor
    return 0;
}
```

[Demo 1.](http://ideone.com/vd9694)

When you write your own copy constructor, you should route the call to an appropriate constructor with parameters, like this:

```
struct Demo {
    Demo() = delete;
    Demo(int _x) : x(_x) { cout << "one-arg constructor" << endl; }
    Demo(const Demo& other) : Demo(other.x) {cout << "copy constructor" << endl; }
    int x;
};
```

[Demo 2.](http://ideone.com/q0YXgj)

Answer (score 4):

The answer is No.

The creation of the object memory is done via the `new` instruction.
Copy constructor is then in charge of the actual copying (relevant only when it's not a shallow copy, obviously).

You can, if you want, explicitly call a different constructor prior to the copy constructor execution.

You can easily test this by copy/paste this code and running it ...

```
#include <stdio.h>

class Ctest
{
public:

    Ctest()
    {
        printf("default constructor");
    }

    Ctest(const Ctest& input)
    {
        printf("Copy Constructor");
    }
};


int main()
{    
    Ctest *a = new Ctest();     //<-- This should call the default constructor

    Ctest *b = new Ctest(*a);  //<-- this will NOT call the default constructor
}
```